# Map texture over a mesh with Mayavi

Tags: python, python-2.7, vtk, texture-mapping, mayavi

I am trying to plot Earth in 3D using python.

I made a script from what I found on the internet and using Mayavi I successfully plotted a mesh but I would like to apply a texture from an image ([a blue marble from NASA](https://eoimages.gsfc.nasa.gov/images/imagerecords/74000/74218/world.200412.3x5400x2700.jpg)).

However when I try to do so, the texture only apply on one half of the ellipsoid and si symmetrically duplicated on the other half.

Here pictures of my result:
[Earth 3D (imgur gallery)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hgt36.jpg)

And my code:

```
import numpy as np
import vtk
from mayavi import mlab

image_file = 'earth_texture.jpg';

erad    = 6371008.7714 # equatorial radius (meters)
prad    = 6371008.7714 # polar radius (meters)
erot    = 7.2921158553e-5 # earth rotation rate (radians/sec)

textureReader = vtk.vtkJPEGReader()
textureReader.SetFileName('earth_texture.jpg')
texture = vtk.vtkTexture()
texture.SetInputConnection(textureReader.GetOutputPort())

u = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 180)
v = np.linspace(0, np.pi, 180)

x = erad * np.outer(np.cos(u), np.sin(v))
y = erad * np.outer(np.sin(u), np.sin(v))
z = prad * np.outer(np.ones_like(u), np.cos(v))

mlab.figure(size=(800, 800), bgcolor=(0.16, 0.28, 0.46))

mesh = mlab.mesh(x,y,z)
mesh.actor.actor.mapper.scalar_visibility=False
mesh.actor.enable_texture = True
mesh.actor.tcoord_generator_mode = 'plane'
mesh.actor.actor.texture = texture
mlab.show()
```

I would like the image to fit the ellipsoid perfectly but I did not find a way to do so.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Map an image onto a sphere and plot 3D trajectories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53074908/map-an-image-onto-a-sphere-and-plot-3d-trajectories)

Comment: I added a detailed answer to the linked duplicate, it covers why you see the weird mirroring behaviour. You'll probably also need `'sphere'` mapping for the Blue Marble images.