# Earth Textured Sphere in Jupyter Notebook using Mayavi

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, mayavi

In a Jupyter notebook I am trying to implement the algorithm, provided in the answer below:

[Map an image onto a sphere and plot 3D trajectories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53074908/map-an-image-onto-a-sphere-and-plot-3d-trajectories)

It works great in a stand alone python file but when I provide the same implementation in a notebook I end up with only a black sphere instead of textured sphere. Below is the cell I use in the notebook:

```
from mayavi import mlab
mlab.init_notebook(local=True)
from tvtk.api import tvtk
import numpy as np

img = tvtk.JPEGReader()
img.file_name = "blue_marble.jpg"
# map the texture
texture = tvtk.Texture(input_connection=img.output_port, interpolate=0)

# make the sphere
R = 1
Nrad = 180

# create the sphere
sphere = tvtk.TexturedSphereSource(radius=R, theta_resolution=Nrad,  
  phi_resolution=Nrad)
#assembly required
sphere_mapper = tvtk.PolyDataMapper(input_connection=sphere.output_port)
sphere_actor = tvtk.Actor(mapper=sphere_mapper, texture=texture)
# plot
mlab.clf()
fig = mlab.figure(size=(800, 600), bgcolor=(1,1,1))
fig.scene.add_actor(sphere_actor)
fig
```

Thanks!

Comment: did you install the mayavi extensions? https://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/tips.html#using-mayavi-in-jupyter-notebooks

Comment: yes, the mayavi extensions work. If I do the mayavi test_points3d function it displays.

Comment: Sounds like you'll need to file an issue: https://github.com/enthought/mayavi/issues

Comment: I will do that, thanks!