# Animation of sphere rotation in Mayavi

Tags: python, plot, mayavi

I am using Mayavi to simulate satellite trajectories, and hence need the sphere which is the main central body to rotate, as the satellite moves, but I can not seem to be able to find a way to change the orientation of the sphere which is in fact a TVTK Actor object, as I am using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53074908/map-an-image-onto-a-sphere-and-plot-3d-trajectories) method to apply the texture. Is there a way or will I have to find another way to implement the texture on the sphere and then rotate it? Thank You for the help. I am also open to using another python library which can help me achieve this.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

In this example, we will animate the rotation of a sphere in Mayavi.

We will create a sphere source and rotate it using a Transform node.

We will also add a scalar cut plane to visualize the rotation.

import numpy as np from mayavi import mlab # Create a sphere source sphere = mlab.pipeline.scalar_field(x, y, z) # Rotate the sphere using a Transform node transform = mlab.pipeline.transform_data(sphere) transform.transform.rotate(angle=0.2, axis=(1, 0, 0)) # Add a scalar cut plane cut_plane = mlab.pipeline.scalar_cut_plane(transform) # Animate the rotation anim = mlab.animate(100) # Rotate the sphere for i in range(100): transform.transform.rotate(angle=0.2, axis=(1, 0, 0)) mlab.draw() anim.save('rotating_sphere.gif', figure=mlab.gcf())

Comment: I tried this but using the scalar field I am not able to get a sphere to show up. I am sorry but I am quite new to mayavi and so I have no idea what I am doing wrong

Comment: Whitespace is important in Python. Please [edit] this to add newlines and proper indentation.